# Generate coordinates for abstract triangulation

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology, triangulation

I have an abstract triangulation, which consists of nodes without coordinates and connectivity information (the triangles themselves). I also know that each link has a fixed length. For simplicity we will say that all links have the *same* length.

From this graph I would like to render a 3d image. I have constructed my triangulation in such a way that it has the topology of a torus. So what I'd like to generate is coordinates for each node such that the triangles are part of the surface of a torus.

Is there a way to do this? And also, is there a way to do this without knowing beforehand that the triangulation has the form of a torus? I imagine a 2d case where a line divided into four segments with periodic boundary conditions becomes a square.